# why the 'value.length' is undefined? (STS)

Tags: javascript

```
<td>
            <input type="radio" name="division" value="personal" checked="checked"/>Personal &nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="division" value="company"/>Company &nbsp;
            </td>
<script>
var division1 = document.getElementsByName("division");
var divLength = division1.value.length;
var division;
for(var i=0 ; i<divLength ; i++){
    if(division1[i].checked){
        division = division1[i];
    }
}
```

why the 'var divLength = division1.value.length;' is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

That's because [getElementsByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a list of nodes.
In order to have access to a single element with the right syntax.

```
var divLength = division[0].value.length; // Using zero indexing on nodes list
```

If you want to access all nodes one by one, you should use a for loop:

```
divisions.forEach((division) => {
  length = division.value.length;
})
```

Or, even better, if you want only to extract the length from each node, you should try the the [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) syntax:

```
lengths = Array.from(divisions).map((division) => division.value.length);
```